# Removing names from boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

How to remove from boxplot data$(column name), because `axes=false` didn't work. `axes=false` just removed the box. Adding `mtext("...",side=..)` just goes over the data$(column name)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try `boxplot(data,xaxt="n",xlab="")`. But for further questions I recommend you on doing some research before asking